# c# calling mysql sp procedure incorrect integer values

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a c# application calling a mysql stored procedure. This was running since 2 years without a problem. Now I made a new installation with the newest mysql db as well .net connector and I get one error after the other.

1st error occured:
I get the error message "InvalidCast". Data was inserted all correctly. I found out, that I have to add "check parameters=falls" in the connection string. Indeed this solved the problem and I got the real error: Expected parameters 42, received parameters 43. Interesting that at this point of time no data is inserted anymore in the db.
So, this was really a bug and I updated table and sp, so that it has 43 parameters

2nd error occured:
Now I got an error telling me that an integer could not be converted. In my DB I have some fields with TinyInt. In c# it is int. These fields have values of 1,2 or 3. Nevertheless, I could not insert anymore them into the db. Before it was running thoudands of times.
So I converted the db fields to INT. This solved the problem. But another error occured

3rd error occured: "Incorrect integer value: "none" for column "p_myparam" at row 220.
Why now this error happens is a mistery. Naturally the value is not none, it is 142. I have now no idea where to search and how to solve the problem.

I have to note, that on my old pc I have absolutely the identical database with identical data and identical c# application. It is still running without a problem. I really wonder how the heck suddenly inserts into TinyInt fields are not possible anymore and worse I get error No 3.

If anybody has an idea, I appreciate any help

thanks

Comment: First thing to remember is that `tinyint` is just an 8-bit integer.  A regular `int` is 32-bit, so that is a very large loss in precision on that, so I understand that error completely.  As far as the 3rd error, I'm not sure what the problem is there.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. this means, TinyInt and SmallInt should never be used in MySQL when working with c#?

Comment: not necessarily.  C# has `int16`, which corresponds to `smallint`.  For `tinyint`, your best option in C# is `byte`.

Comment: I investigated more into this. Error 3 happens because parameters are no more checked in the SP call. Naturally a bad idea to have "checkparaemters=false" in the connection string. I really wonder why the heck this is listed as workaround in mysql.

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with tinyint etc. see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is found. In my code I had this statement:

```
long returnID= (long) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

With previous version of MySQL Server and .net connector this worked fine.  With the newest upgrade no more. It should now be as follows:

```
object returnID = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Why this change is needed, no idea.

Most annoying about this is the complete useless error message given by ExecuteScalar. Just telling that a conversion does not work in a SP with over 40 parameters does not help.